# Inconsistent page has expired message in internet explorer

Tags: python, internet-explorer, zope

I have an application developed in Python-Zope where only on some of the pages, I am getting "page has expired issue" and this does not come every time. This issue comes when I click on "Back" or "Cancel" buttons which use browser history to redirect to the earlier pages. I have reviewed my code and there is not code setting response headers to prevent page caching.

Also the issue is with internet explorer only and code works fine with mozilla.

Is there a way I can prevent this message?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your page served on HTTPS?

If so this is the expected behavior. By default IE will not cache a secured page on disk, nor will it automatically resubmit pages with POST data.

This is security feature (prevent cache sniffing, etc) and is about the only thing IE does correctly.

Comment: Yes, the page is served on HTTPS. I am actually surprised that it is not happening every time I click on the back or cancel button.

Comment: The browser only fetch "regular" `GET` pages automatically. This error only come up on pages submit with `POST` data.